# Full disk encryption affects remote wipe ability?

Tags: remote-wipe, disk-encryption

Android's FDE affects remote wipe effectiveness, say, with Android Device Manager?

What I mean is this:

If one does not have system encryption enabled, to safely wipe all your data would require overwriting all your data. One would think that having full disk encryption enabled would allow wiping by just erasing the encryption keys. Is this so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you still would be able to remotely wipe it as encryption only as the name says "encrypts" the data. That means that after provided a password the file will unlock itself for read, but this doesn't affect deletion :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no link between FDE and remote wipe. The effectiveness of remote wipe is as good with FDE as it is without it. All that remote wipe depends on is that the phone is switched on and able to access some form of network.

Comment: Do you have any link for this?